# What are local isomorphisms and how sheaves serve as localization of presheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, localization

I'm confusing about the following statement:

> The category of sheaves is the localization of the category of presheaves respect to the local isomorphisms.

But what are local isomorphisms?
According to the [nLab entry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local+isomorphism), it seems that the following definition is correct:

> A presheaf morphism is a local isomorphism iff it becomes an isomorphism after applying the sheafification.

I'm right?

If so, then how to prove the first statement?

More precisely, the sheafification $\mathscr{F}^{\sharp}$ of a presheaf $\mathscr{F}$ should satisfying
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{F}^{\sharp}(U) = Hom_{Sh(\mathcal{C})}(\hat{U},\mathscr{F}^{\sharp}).
\end{equation}
Therefore, I need to show
\begin{equation}
\mathscr{F}^{\sharp}(U) = \underrightarrow{\lim}_{LI_U} Hom_{PSh(\mathcal{C})}(\mathscr{U},\mathscr{F}),
\end{equation}
where $LI_U$ is the subcategory of $PSh(\mathcal{C})/\Upsilon(U)$ consisting of only local isomorphisms.

**But how?**

Obviously there is a canonical map from the colimit to $\mathscr{F}^{\sharp}(U)$ induced from the composes:
\begin{equation}
 Hom_{PSh(\mathcal{C})}(\mathscr{U},\mathscr{F})\to Hom_{Sh(\mathcal{C})}(\mathscr{U}^{sharp},\mathscr{F}^{sharp})\to Hom_{Sh(\mathcal{C})}(\hat{U},\mathscr{F}^{\sharp})
\end{equation}
where the second map is induced by the inverse of the sheafification of $\mathscr{U}\to\Upsilon(U)$.

How to show this canonical map is an isomorphism?

Comment: You should probably look up the plus construction for sheafification. The ideas are similar.

Comment: @ZhenLin I know applying twice plus construction will provide sheafification. But here one only takes once colimit.

Comment: Sure. But I'm advising you to look at the _proof_.

Comment: @ZhenLin, So you mean prove this colimit defines a sheaf and gives rise to a left adjoint to the inclusion $Sh\to PSh$, thus must be the sheafification, just like what one dose for puls construction, right?

Comment: That is what you are trying to do, yes.